# Need help due to a PyGame error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm developing a Space Invaders clone using Python 3.5.1 and PyGame. My issue is that I cannot manage to load my sprites onto the screen. I keep receiving the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\supmanigga\Documents\Space Invaders\spaceinvaders.py", line 44, in 
    allSprites.draw(screen)
  File "C:\Users\supmanigga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'image'

My code is as follows:

```
import pygame
import sys

width = 500
height = 700

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

score = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("laser").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

player = Ship()
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
allSprites.add(player)

running = True
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)

    allSprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

`def _init_(self):` should be `def __init__(self):`

Otherwise, the line `self.image = pygame.image.load("player").convert()` is never executed, and thus your `Ship` instance will have no `image` attribute.